# How to keep on writing on the same csv file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm, cron

I'm using this [nodejs package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) in order to write some data to a CSV file every minute, so far the creation of the file is ok, also the first time write is ok, but when it comes the time to write again on the same file nodejs throws me error, I tried to look around for a solution but I came up whit nothing, hope someone could help me out. I'll post what I have right now

```
var cronCSV = require('node-schedule');
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false});
var ruleCSV = new cron.RecurrenceRule();
ruleCSV.second = 1;
const fs = require('fs');
writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'))
//SOME OTHER CODE

    cronCSV.scheduleJob(ruleCSV, function(){

        writer.write({hPerc: hPerc, humidity: humidity});
        writer.end();
        console.log("Scritto su CSV");
    });
```

And the error:

```
_stream_readable.js:501
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at CsvWriteStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:501:7)
    at Job.job (/home/pi/node_led/main.js:64:10)
    at Job.invoke (/home/pi/node_led/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:175:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/pi/node_led/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:479:11)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Comment: "throws me error" — Exactly what does the error message say?

Comment: @Quentin edited the question to include error right now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the pipe just after writing to it first (and each) time:

You should remove this row:

```
writer.end();
```

If the process is intended to finish any time, then it would be a good idea to execute it just before that. But not when you expect to write to it more times.

Comment: Right..such a stupid question I made..that's why i could not find an answer, thanks very much

Comment: I also noticed that "writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'))" delete the content of the csv file everytime I stop and run the application..is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: You can open the file in append mode instead of write. I'm not sure how to do i with streams, but sure there is a way to approach it. The problem I see is that csvWriter wil also insert again the header (which will be seen as a data row in the file). BTW, csvWriter would probably have some option to avoid it. If it exists, you could check if the file exists or not to decide if the header must be generated.

Comment: On the other hand, if you haven't any complex data fields (involving problematic characters such as quotes or newlines, etc…) you can simply generate the csv header and data rows by hand, whic is too easy if, as I said, you know you will never have such problematic dada…